# Python:OpenCV reading images and dtype assignment

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

noob here to python and OpenCV. I see code examples where people simply load RGB images using

```
img=cv2.imread('PATH')
```

Then I start to see other codes that actually assigned data types:

```
img = cv2.imread('DATA/bricks.jpg').astype(np.float32)/255
```

And others using dtype = np.uint8

I'm confused for 1) when should I specify the image to dtype? and 2) should I go for uint8 or float32?

Some pointers and good readings for what they actually do would be much appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. You typically load an image using [cv2.imread](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) (which also supports a set of flags, depending on the type of image you are working with) without further conversion unless you need it down the line. If you have typical `JPEG` images, you just read them using imread and they will be loaded as a 3-channel `NumPy` array of `uint8` (unsigned, 8 bits per channel)  pixels – that’s the data type that usually represents images.

Comment: However, [float data](http://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/PFM/) can also be used. Some image processing operations need or yield float data types (such as division or [normalization](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd)), so some conversions are sometimes needed. It all depends on your application.

Comment: @eldesgraciado, I see. Thank you mate! indeed in the uint8 example, they are indeed just reading in jpeg files and checking the size and dimensions. In the float data code, they are doing more fancy blurring and smoothing of the images. For myself, I will be dealing with micrograph images in biology, in TIFF format, to detect objects and edges. So I guess I should read more on the float data operations?

Comment: `TIFF` images are also decoded into `uint8`. In general, you should read images as  `uint8` unless using "native" floating point images such as `PFM`, which is a very specific case. However, depending on the operations you perform, you could need a conversion into another data type. For example, you might need to multiply an image (actually a matrix) by a `float` constant. This would produce a `float` result, which cannot be displayed as an image, since it must be `uint8` . So, you would perform a conversion from `float` back to `uint8`.

Comment: @eldesgraciado thank you for the tips man. yes, I think I literally just saw the multiply example today to adjust for the colour today. This makes perfect sense now